# Why does this exception happen?

Tags: java, lucene

```
ERROR com.snapwiz.service.impl.ExceptionAdviceLoger -  Exception - Object : com.snapwiz.service.impl.CourseServiceImpl@1df5d05 method : public abstract void com.snapwiz.service.CourseService.updateLessonContent(com.snapwiz.model.dao.LessonContent) args : [com.snapwiz.model.dao.LessonContent@176afcd]
2011-04-29 03:48:01,813 [TP-Processor15] ERROR com.snapwiz.service.impl.ExceptionAdviceLoger -  Exception 
org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDeviceException: {hibernateDevice}: Failed while updating [com.snapwiz.model.dao.Lesson@14f0f22]; nested exception is org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Failed to process job [Job Update [alias [lesson] uid [lesson#1497#]] Resource [{lesson} [stored/uncompressed,indexed,omitNorms<alias:lesson>],[stored/uncompressed,indexed,omitNorms,omitTf<$/entity/id:1497>],[stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<lesson-description:A Charged Isolated Conductor>],[stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<lesson-name:A Charged Isolated Conductor>],[stored/uncompressed,indexed,omitNorms,omitTf<$/uid:lesson#1497#>]]]; nested exception is org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: PhantomReadLock[write.lock/index_lesson]
org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Failed to process job [Job Update [alias [lesson] uid [lesson#1497#]] Resource [{lesson} [stored/uncompressed,indexed,omitNorms<alias:lesson>],[stored/uncompressed,indexed,omitNorms,omitTf<$/entity/id:1497>],[stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<lesson-description:A Charged Isolated Conductor>],[stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<lesson-name:A Charged Isolated Conductor>],[stored/uncompressed,indexed,omitNorms,omitTf<$/uid:lesson#1497#>]]]; nested exception is org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: PhantomReadLock[write.lock/index_lesson]
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: PhantomReadLock[write.lock/index_lesson]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:85)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1070)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1011)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.IndexWritersManager.openIndexWriter(IndexWritersManager.java:133)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.IndexWritersManager.openIndexWriter(IndexWritersManager.java:123)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.IndexWritersManager.openIndexWriter(IndexWritersManager.java:115)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.IndexWritersManager.openIndexWriter(IndexWritersManager.java:111)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.transaction.readcommitted.ReadCommittedTransactionProcessor.openIndexWriterIfNeeded(ReadCommittedTransactionProcessor.java:435)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.transaction.readcommitted.ReadCommittedTransactionProcessor.doProcessJob(ReadCommittedTransactionProcessor.java:341)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.transaction.support.AbstractConcurrentTransactionProcessor.update(AbstractConcurrentTransactionProcessor.java:170)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.LuceneSearchEngine.createOrUpdate(LuceneSearchEngine.java:285)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.LuceneSearchEngine.save(LuceneSearchEngine.java:263)
    at org.compass.core.impl.DefaultCompassSession.save(DefaultCompassSession.java:489)
    at org.compass.core.impl.DefaultCompassSession.save(DefaultCompassSession.java:473)
    at org.compass.core.impl.ExistingCompassSession.save(ExistingCompassSession.java:313)
    at org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.HibernateEventListener.doUpdate(HibernateEventListener.java:248)
    at org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.HibernateEventListener$2.doInCompassWithoutResult(HibernateEventListener.java:141)
    at org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult.doInCompass(CompassCallbackWithoutResult.java:29)
    at org.compass.core.CompassTemplate.execute(CompassTemplate.java:133)
    at org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps.executeForMirror(SingleCompassGps.java:151)
    at org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.HibernateEventListener.onPostUpdate(HibernateEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.postUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$28.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:883)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.flush(HibernateTemplate.java:881)
    at com.snapwiz.model.db.BaseCRUD.updateObject(BaseCRUD.java:69)
    at com.snapwiz.service.impl.CourseServiceImpl.updateLessonContent(CourseServiceImpl.java:1059)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy13.updateLessonContent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy14.updateLessonContent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy14.updateLessonContent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy14.updateLessonContent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy14.updateLessonContent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy14.updateLessonContent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy14.updateLessonContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.snapwiz.service.impl.ContentServiceImpl.updateLesson(ContentServiceImpl.java:762)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3556.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy43.updateLesson(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3556.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy44.updateLesson(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3556.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy44.updateLesson(Unknown Source)
    at com.snapwiz.web.LessonEditorController.onSubmit(LessonEditorController.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.processFormSubmission(SimpleFormController.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:151)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.snapwiz.web.filter.NoAjaxPageDecorationFilter.doFilter(NoAjaxPageDecorationFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.snapwiz.security.filter.DecryptRequestParametersFilter.doFilterInternal(DecryptRequestParametersFilter.java:26)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at com.snapwiz.security.filter.SessionExpirationFilter.doFilter(SessionExpirationFilter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.snapwiz.security.filter.SpringSecurityAjaxFilter.doFilterInternal(SpringSecurityAjaxFilter.java:34)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
```

Comment: Because there was a timeout obtaining the lock: http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/Lock.html#obtain(long) For a more useful response, you'll have to **show your code**.

Answer (score 1):

> This exception is thrown when the write.lock could not be acquired. This happens when a writer tries to open an index that another writer already has open.

[(lucene API javadoc)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/store/LockObtainFailedException.html)

The index is already locked.

Comment: @user622688 - not with that little information. Analyze your code - do you have more then one writer? Are they releasing the locks? Did you app crash and the index is still locked (then you should see some sort of *lock* file near the index file)

Answer (score 0):

Are you committing this transaction?

```
com.snapwiz.model.db.BaseCRUD.updateObject(BaseCRUD.java:69)
com.snapwiz.service.impl.CourseServiceImpl.updateLessonContent(CourseServiceImpl.java:1059)
```

Also, there is a SOLR bug that may be related https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-240

Comment: in admin module, admis adding lessions and saving to db...that time this exception is coming..>?

Comment: Do you have the source of these two classes I referred to in my previous comment?

Comment: No,we are not commit transaction. public final void updateObject(final Object object) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(object);
        getHibernateTemplate().flush();
    }

Comment: public void updateLessonContent(LessonContent lessonContent) {
  baseCRUD.updateObject(lessonContent);
 }